# Slicing Numpy Array by 2 index arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have a set of indices stored in two Numpy arrays, my goal is to slice a given input array based on corresponding indices in those index arrays. For eg.

```
index_arr1 = np.asarray([2,3,4])
index_arr2 = np.asarray([5,5,6])

input_arr = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,4,5,7,2])
```

The output to my code should be `[[3,4,4],[4,4],[4,5]]` which is basically `[input_arr[2:5], input_arr[3:5], input_arr[4:6]]`

Can anybody suggest a way to solve this problem using numpy functions and avoiding any for loops to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: There's no `numpy` magic to take multiple slices like this (especially with overlapping slices of differing length).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
[input_arr[x:y] for x,y in zip(index_arr1, index_arr2)]
```

Output:

```
[array([3, 4, 4]), array([4, 4]), array([4, 5])]
```

Or if you really want list of lists:

```
[[input_arr[x:y].tolist() for x,y in zip(index_arr1, index_arr2)]
```

Output:

```
[[3, 4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for some 'numpy magic' but I think list comprehensions are faster than for loops as well.

Comment: Numpy magic would be hard since your output is unlikely a n-D array. I'd be interested in such a solution also.